# With the revelation of Jones's ally/leader in Season 4 how does that change Season 1

Tags: fringe

In Season 1 there were strong implications of a connection between Massive Dyanamic (Bell and Nina), and the Pattern/ZFT (David Robert Jones).  Nina pretty heavily denied them and there always was a layer of plausible deniability.

> But with the revelation of Nina pulling Jones's strings thru the typewriter, how does this recast Nina, and Bell's role in ZFT?  Both of them were focused on defending "Over Here" universe from the other universe.  ZFT was Walter's playbook of how to defend against the other universe, sans the morals bit.  And it is shown that Nina is knowingly involved with experiments on children along the lines of the cortexiphan trials into season 2([Of human Action](http://fringepedia.net/wiki/Of_Human_Action)).

Does this mean in Season 1 Nina was as involved with ZFT as she is in Season 4?  If so, how did she hinder the Fringe team in fighting ZFT?  And was Jones's attack on her staged or does it indicate that Nina was moving away from supporting ZFT and moved towards the Fringe team?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The end of *[A Better Human Being](http://fringepedia.net/wiki/A_Better_Human_Being)* (Season 4 episode 11) brings a new light to this :

> Olivia was abducted and imprisoned along with Nina, while there's another Nina at Massive Dynamic with Walter and Agent Lee.

So don't know which Nina it is that Jones communicates with in *[Enemy Of My Enemy](http://fringepedia.net/wiki/Enemy_Of_My_Enemy)*(Season 4 episode 9). We also don't know which Nina is which in the above spoiler section, but we are sure there are at least 2 Ninas. Any of them could be :

1. *Over Here*'s Nina, the one who raised Olivia.
2. *Over There*'s Nina ?
3. A Shapeshifter ?

The only thing we learn in *[The End Of All Things](http://fringepedia.net/wiki/The_End_Of_All_Things)*(Season 4 episode 12) is that :

> The Nina imprisoned along with Olivia is not the one who raised Olivia since she did not know she didn't called her 'Nina' until her high-school graduation.

So we cannot conclude to anything as from now. 
(Will update whenever new information is revealed.)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't read anything into this at all. It's a new timeline and we have no way of knowing whether anything "new" in S4 can be retroactively used to explain plot points in S1.